# How to move the flutter app bar logo to center left

Tags: flutter, appbar

I want to show a logo on app bar and am achieving it through the following code.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 3,
      title: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo/logo.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      )),
```

**Output am getting**

[image]

> The problem here is The icon is centered how can I stick to the right like this

**Desired Output**

[image]

> As in the above code I already tried

```
 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Still not working anyone have any idea? Please support.

Comment: Try to set `automaticallyImplyLeading` property to false in the `Appbar` Widget.

Comment: Thanks friend this helped (: If you post the answer I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is simply because of the Default Leading applied to The app bar as you navigate from the other page and somehow that leading icon is in white color.

> If you enable the Show Boundaries in the Dev tools you can see the Default leading icon is taking that blank spot.

### There are two possible outcomes to this problem.

```
You can change the color to any visible color.

- This will help the user to navigate back.
```

```
You can try to set the "automaticallyImplyLeading" property to "false" in the "Appbar" Widget.

- This will disable the default leading icon in the Appbar.
```

Comment: Yes , you are right

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you are almost there with your code. Here is the snippet that'll place your logo in left inside appbar.

```
AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 3,
      title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/nividata-logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
            ),
          ])),
```

Okay, as you can see I've just used row and gave mainAxisAlignment to start, so that'll place every element inside row from start.

If I change this to below code, then It'll start placing elements from right side (end).

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
```

You can also check below screenshots for results that I'm getting with above code.
[image]
[image]

Comment: see am also using `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,` in my code. But still it's not going to start

Comment: Please try to copy my code and try to run, I got logo on left from your code as well. I don't think your code is wrong, may be you haven't added all code. May be some other code is blocking expected result.

Comment: Yes your answer is logically correct but, This helped me to fix this issue. `automaticallyImplyLeading:false`. Thanks for the answer I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. just change your widgets inside action tag(like your image)

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title:Image.network(
      'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/kiev-ukraine-may-03-2015-260nw-275974145.jpg',
    ),
    automaticallyImplyLeading:false,
    actions: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.add),
      Icon(Icons.person),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: I want the image as logo. I don't want `title:Text('title here')`. see in my code I am using a row widget to show the image as logo. `title: Row()....`.

Comment: check updated answer and just change your image instead of my image

Comment: This helped me to fix this issue. `automaticallyImplyLeading:false`. Thanks for the answer .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, got the answer from one of the comment.
`automaticallyImplyLeading:false`.
This fixed the issue